# Magento Blocks HTML Output cache problem

Tags: blocks, cache, html

I have a problem with my Magento website.

Because my website was extensively redesigned, notably the home page - I have had the cache disabled on the page for about a month or two.

Now I was able to enable all cache modules except Blocks HTML Output module. When I switch it on, my Magento is displaying the old home page. Sometimes it also says that cache is Invalidated.

Refreshing and flushing cache does nothing. So does the manual deletion of files from var/cache folder.

I am clueless. I've heard that usually, people have a problem with products not showing due to blocks html but this is really confusing. How can I rectify this problem?

Comment: Are you using any other cache?

Comment: As mbalparda asked - are you using any other cache as APC, Memcache or Varnish (Varnish makes the most problems)? Also you can check if Compiler is enabled and to disable or recompile it (in the admin panel -> System -> Tools -> Compilation).

Comment: All other cache are now enabled only blocks html output is disabled

Comment: I also have ezzoom plugin in operation

Answer (score 2):

You may be using an alternative cache backend, in which case, using the `Flush Cache Storage` button should be sufficient to empty the cache contents.

If you are using a cache backend that doesn't support tagging (eg. Memcache), then conditionally flushing caches isn't going to work (unless you are using two-level caching).

You can verify the cache backend by looking in your `./app/etc/local.xml` file between the `<cache/>` tags.