# Blocks HTML output cache issue, static blocks not displayed when enable this in magento 1.9.2.4?

Tags: admin, cache, static-block, magento1.9.2.4

I have an issue, When I enable **Blocks HTML output** cache My static blocks were not displayed in product description page, when I disable this everything is working fine.
Please suggest what can I do to fix this.

Comment: Have you flush your cache?

Comment: yes.. But nothing works for me.

Comment: Actually I'm Magento 2 developer, so I'm sorry I can't assist you further more in Magento 1. This question may help you: [Magento 1.9.2.0 Static Block Display Issues](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73685/magento-1-9-2-0-static-block-display-issues)

Comment: Thanks @RendyEkoPrastiyo, I already checked this but nothing works for me.

Comment: Do you use other cache manager? Check this question out: [Magento Blocks HTML Output Cache Problem](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45386/magento-blocks-html-output-cache-problem)